# JQuery scrolling to a div inside a div with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I want to scroll to a specific div which is inside a div that has scrollbars.

[image]

```
var div_terms = $('#div_terms').offset();

    $("#scroll_to_accept").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: div_terms.top}, "slow");
        //});
    });
```

Div terms is the div inside the scrollable div. The link to click to scroll that div is in the `<legend>` which is outside the `<fieldset>` `div`.

What I want is as soon as the user clicks on the "scroll to end and accept" the div should scroll down to the "div_terms" div as shown in the figure.

Comment: where did you hear `error` is deprecated?

Comment: @DevZer0 depreciated != deprecated. You are working too hard take some rest. :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i am having fun, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: guys let me know if my syntax and flow is correct.

Comment: it's jqXHR.error(), .success() and .complete() that's being deprecated, not ajax(settings.error). The doc is mixing ajax and jqXHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. scroll_to_accept is the id of the link to click.
2. terms is the id of scrollable div
3. div_terms is the position there it needs to be scrolled.

   ```
   var div_terms = $('#div_terms').offset();
   $("#scroll_to_accept").click(function (){   
           scroll_to_terms();
   });

   function scroll_to_terms()
   {
         $('#terms').animate({scrollTop: div_terms.top}, "slow");
   }
   ```